# JVM memory in smartfoxserver

Tags: java, gameserver

We have developed a multiplayer game using smartfoxserver as gameserver.

I've setup a Ubuntu Instance 14.10 LTS in AWS with 2 Core 8GB Ram for only gameserver.

But when I log into SFS admin. It says Max:1.8GB, Free:130mb. There are hardly 10 users playing at the moment and the Free memory goes down to 1.3mb sometimes.

Please advice me on the below points

> 1) Why is this Max1.8GB when I have 8GB memory ??
>  2) Out of 1.8GB,
>   does smartfoxserver consume 1.7GB ??
>  3) Shall I increase the
>   memory. If yes, please advice me on how to increase the memory.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid crashing your server, the JVM will only allocate as much memory as you told it to allocate on the Java command line. So you will need to edit start.sh to allocate more memory if you need more. Here's the options I added to the Java command line on a server with 8gb of memory where I wanted to use most of the memory for Java but leave enough for the OS to run well:

```
-Xms512m -Xmx4560m -XX:MaxPermSize=500m
```

You can look up those options in the Java documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html .

Comment: but I always restart via sfs2x-service...Shall i add this in this file eric ??